# Import @socketio.on() from another class in Flask

Tags: python, import, flask, socket.io, handlers

I'm making a new application with Flask and socketio. The code simplified is like this:

```
socketio = SocketIO(app)

@socketio.on('connect', namespace='/test')
def test_connect():
    print('Client connected')
    emit('my response', {'data': 'User Connected'}, broadcast = True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app, '0.0.0.0', 8080)
```

I'm not sure how could I import the "handler: **@socketio.on('connect', namespace='/test')**" from another class so I don't overload the main class.

I guess Blueprints could be a solution, but I've only found how to use them with the "routes". I'm not sure if this would work with the sockets.

Could anyone give me a hand? Thanks all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you can do this is by moving the `socketio.on()` functions to a different module. You mention classes, but these are really functions, the way to structure your application is by separating the different parts of it into modules or packages.

Take a look at [this example](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO-Chat) that I created to demonstrate one way to structure a Flask application that uses Flask-SocketIO.

Comment: Thanks for the example link, it's a lifesaver.

Comment: In my example, my socket emit occurs within a background task using ThreadPoolExecutor. It is called from a library --> concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor. How can I call this library from the main script?